# Weaviate cloud services add module

Tags: weaviate

How would I add a modules to a cluster in weaviate cloud services. If I could not add it after creation of a cluster could I do it before?

I know that I could do it with docker compose but there is no option to add modules in weaviate cloud services

I am trying to add `text2vec-contextionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, every module has a section if [a module is available](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/modules/retriever-vectorizer-modules/text2vec-contextionary#weaviate-cloud-services) on the Weaviate Cloud Service. The `text2vec-contextionary` isn't. Feel free to raise this on the [forum](https://forum.weaviate.io) or on the [Slack](https://weaviate.io/slack) channel.

Comment: how would I recreate a weaviate cluster using docker in cloud services ? i am unsure if I should use shardaring. Anyway this is the correct answer and will accept it sadly :(. For anyone viewing in the future it would make sense to vectorize first then upload to weaviate

Comment: This depends, most other modules for vectorization are supported :)